# How to iterate over an ActiveRecord resultset in one line with nil check in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, one-liner

I have an array of Active Record result and I want to iterate over each record to get a specific attribute and add all of them in one line with a nil check. Here is what I got so far

```
def total_cost(cost_rec)
    total= 0.0
    unless cost_rec.nil?
      cost_rec.each { |c| total += c.cost }
    end
    total
  end
```

Is there an elegant way to do the same thing in one line?

Comment: If you are trying to sum values from a column I'll suggest try to get the sum straight from the database instead of looping through all the objects. It should be way more performant (in terms of speed and resources)

Comment: at the moment I have to do the sum outside the db, but agree with you it would be better if can be done within the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine safe-navigation (to "hide" the `nil` check), summation inside the database (to avoid pulling a bunch of data out of the database that you don't need), and a `#to_f` call to hide the final `nil` check:

```
cost_rec&.sum(:cost).to_f
```

If the `cost` is an integer, then:

```
cost_rec&.sum(:cost).to_i
```

and if `cost` is a `numeric` inside the database and you don't want to worry about precision issues:

```
cost_rec&.sum(:cost).to_d
```

If `cost_rec` is an array rather than a relation (i.e. you've already pulled all the data out of the database), then one of:

```
cost_rec&.sum(&:cost).to_f
cost_rec&.sum(&:cost).to_i
cost_rec&.sum(&:cost).to_d
```

depending on what type `cost` is.

You could also use `Kernel#Array` to ignore `nil`s (since `Array(nil)` is `[]`) and ignore the difference between arrays and ActiveRecord relations (since `#Array` calls `#to_ary` and relations respond to that) and say:

```
Array(cost_rec).sum(&:cost)
```

that'll even allow `cost_rec` to be a single model instance. This also bypasses the need for the final `#to_X` call since `[].sum` is `0`. The downside of this approach is that you can't push the summation into the database when `cost_rec` is a relation.

Comment: I like your oneliner, but sometime I will have one record only, and sum is giving me error for that. any other option to handle this scenario?

Comment: @soLegacy You can say `Array(cost_rec).sum(&:cost)` in such cases. No need for the `&.` nil check since `Array(nil)` is `[]` and `[].sum` is zero so you don't need the trailing `to_X` call.

Comment: @soLegacy The `#Array` approach is even more flexible as I've noted in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

anything like these?

```
def total_cost(cost_rec)
  (cost_rec || []).inject(0) { |memo, c| memo + c.cost }
end
```

or

```
def total_cost(cost_rec)
  (cost_rec || []).sum(&:cost)
end
```

Comment: There's also `Array(cost_rec).sum(&:cost)` which allows `cost_rec` to be a single model instance, `nil`, an array of models, or an ActiveRecord relation.

Answer (score 1):

Either one of these should work

```
total = cost_rec.map(&:cost).compact.sum
total = cost_rec.map{|c| c.cost }.compact.sum
total = cost_rec.pluck(:cost).compact.sum
```

Edit: if cost_rec is nil

```
total = (cost_rec || []).map{|c| c.cost }.compact.sum
```

Comment: I think you have an issue if cost_rec is nil

Answer (score 0):

When `cost_rec` is an `ActiveRecord::Relatation` then this should work out of the box:

```
cost_rec.sum(:cost)
```

See [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum).